# a weird "no turn on red" traffic ticket

Tags: officials, traffic, new-jersey

this is my first post. My apology if my question doesn't fit in the nature of this forum and please kindly redirect me to the appropriate forum if this is the case.

I was stopped when I drove in Jersey City, NJ, USA by a police officer, on 2/20/20, who cited me for turning right on a "no turn on red" sign.

He was kinda of sold when I told him that I was new to the city and didn't notice the sign, he then issued me a ticket but said no point was taken from my record, and only a small amount of fine was imposed.

I can't ask for too much. However, when I log into the website a few days later in hope to pay my fine, it said something to the effect that "this is not a payable offense and you must appear before a judge".

First of all I hate to make a trip to the court back there because it's a long trip. Secondly I took another look at the ticket, there is a "**Court appearance required**" option but the box wasn't checked.

My best guess, basing on what the officer told me, he might have issued me a wrong ticket. I don't mind paying a fine but what I am in now is a bigger trouble.

I called the court with the number on the ticket, I would say the lady picking up the phone was less than polite, she refused to hear my story. She just demanded my address and said to mail out a new court date on which I must attend otherwise my license will be suspended or revoked.

Today (03/13/20) I received the notice. But again, I feel myself in an information black hole and being pushed around by a bunch of bureaucratic government employees who couldn't care less but only carry out chores by books.

Can anyone have experience advising me what is going on and what's my best course of action?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the part where we tell you to call lawyer. Whenever you have these types of situations, relying on online advice is not the best idea, except if they tell you to call a lawyer!

Comment: *I told him that I was new to the city and didn't notice the sign* This is **very** bad because it tells the police you do not pay attention.

Comment: not really travel related imo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not travel related.  Possibly could be asked on Law SE